# Regular Expression check length

Tags: java, regex

I have been trying to make a regular expression for my mobile phones but I can't seem to get it to work:

Here are the conditions for my regular expression:

- must start with `09`
- total length is `9`

Here is my regular expression:

```
[0]{1}[9]{1}[0-9]{7}
```

**Valid** mobile number `091123456`

**Invalid** mobile number `0991234567` || `09912345`

Comment: Use anchors `^09[0-9]{7}$`

Comment: For more reference "[Regex in java for phone no](http://howtodoinjava.com/regex/java-regex-validate-international-phone-numbers/)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way:

```
^09[0-9]{7}$
```

Explanation:

^09 => begins by 09

[0-9] => any character between 0 and 9

{7} exactly seven times

$ => Ends with the latest group ([0-9]{7})

Answer (score 1):

If you use `matcher.contains()` instead of `matcher.find()` it will match against the whole string instead of trying to find a matching substring. Or you can add `^` and `$` anchors as suggested in other answer.

If you don't *really* need to use a regexp, perhaps it would be more readable to just use

```
string.startsWith("09") && string.length() == 9
```